# Как правильно собирать докер образ с платформозависимым кодом?

Tags: javascript, typescript, docker, webpack, devops

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно автоматизировать сборку докер-образ в следующей ситуации:

У нас есть микросервисы на react (сервер сайд рендеринг), мы используем webpack, typescript и node-sass, все исходники хостятся на битбакете. Как грамотно автоматизировать процесс CI в таких условиях?

Хотелось бы по какому-то триггеру собрать докер образ и запушить его в регистр.

Нынешние знания инфраструктуры докера позволяют нам увидеть следующую картину:

1) Собранное приложение должно быть включено в докер-образ

2) Приложение должно собираться в том же окружении, что и будет запущено в контейнере (версия node должна совпадать с окружением)

Сейчас наш докерфайл до боли простой: докер-образ запускается на официальном образе node + клонит исходники из битбакета + пробрасывает порты на хост, а уже в запущенном контейнере мы устанавливаем зависимости и запускаем сборку приложения, после чего запускаем его

По внутренним ощущениям это крайне неудачный подход, нам кажется, что такое решение как минимум не идиоматично для сообщества.

DevOps в команде, к большому огорчению нет.

Будем признательны за любую информацию.

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines